# Why does Json.Net call the Equals method on my objects when serializing?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, equals, serialization

I just ran into an error when I was using the Newtonsoft.Json `SerializeObject` method. It has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552077/jsonconvert-serializeobject-passes-custom-type-properties-to-parent-types-equals/26552983), but there was no answer from the people working with Newtonsoft as to why this happens.

Basically, when calling `SerializeObject` like this:

```
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(from, new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });
```

I get errors in a lot of `Equals` methods I have overridden in my classes:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return false;

    CapacityConfiguration cc = (CapacityConfiguration)obj; // <-- TypeCastException here; other Properties of the same class are sent in as parameter!
}
```

And of course I realize that it's "easy" to fix, by checking like this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj is CapacityConfiguration == false)
        return false;

    CapacityConfiguration cc = (CapacityConfiguration)obj;
}
```

But the real question is:
**Why does Json.Net send in other types of objects in the `Equals` method of the class?** More specifically, Json.Net seems to send in a lot of other properties in the class, instead of another object of the same type.

To me, it's completely weird. Any input would be appreciated.

I am using "Version 8.0.0.0" according to Visual Studio.

**UPDATE 1**

It's easy to test, as it is reproducible:

```
public class JsonTestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> MyIntList { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        JsonTestClass jtc = (JsonTestClass)obj;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then just place this code in Program.cs or anywhere else:

```
JsonTestClass c = new JsonTestClass();
c.Name = "test";
c.MyIntList = new List<int>();
c.MyIntList.Add(1);

string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c, new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });
```

and you will get the TypeCast Exception:

[image]

Comment: Any chance you can provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Is this just to detect possible cycles in object graphs?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Well, I dont have that ready, no. I was running this when I was convertnig some data in my large project, so I havent made a test-project. I thought maybe it could be something well-known that someone could explain, but I will trt to put together a test and see if I can replicate it there.

Comment: In any case, the likely reason is probably that json.net is seeing if you're serializing cyclic objects (objects which (in)directly refer to themselves). Your `Equals(object)` method should be prepared to handle any type anyway so regardless of json.net, that is the way to do it.

Comment: I have updated my question with "UPDATE 1" above, easy to reproduce. @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Is that a guess or do you know that is a fact? Cause my initial thought was that there is a serious error...?

Comment: @Ted - if you take a look at [Implementing the Equals Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh.aspx) you will see that the overridden `Equals()` methods always check to see whether the incoming object is of the same type as the current object, e.g. *The Point.Equals method checks that the obj argument is not null and that it references an instance of the **same type** as this object.*

Comment: _"Cause my initial thought was that there is a serious error...?"_ - there is, your `Equals()` method is broken.

Comment: hehe, right, I meant with Json.Net, but I guess you got that ;-)

Comment: Note - if you would prefer reference equality to be used, see the workaround mentioned in the answer to [Why doesn't reference loop detection use reference equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46936395/3744182).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Why will JsonConvert.SerializeObject call the `object.Equals` method?

Because when you use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`, there is a method [CheckForCircularReference](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/c90e6e871ae39cd4686dac6fa64a780e527123a8/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs) which is called to check whether a property re-references your own object, leading to an infinite loop.

```
 private bool CheckForCircularReference(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
```

In the `CheckForCircularReference` method, part of code uses the `Contains` method, which will call `object.Equals` if your `object` didn't implement the  `IEquatable<T>` interface.

```
bool exists = (Serializer._equalityComparer != null)
                ? _serializeStack.Contains(value, Serializer._equalityComparer)
                : _serializeStack.Contains(value);
```

**Explanation**

1. `_serializeStack` is a list of objects currently being serialized.
2. The `List<T>.Contains` method checks whether the current property is or isn't contained in the collection.
3. `List<T>.Contains` uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`, which in turn uses `IEquatable<T>` if the type implements it, or `object.Equals` otherwise.
4. The `object value` parameter is your current `Property` object.

---

Here is an [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kspgrY) of a self-referencing loop:

```
public class JsonTestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> MyIntList { get; set; }
    public JsonTestClass Test{get;set;}
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        JsonTestClass jtc = (JsonTestClass)obj;
        return true;
   }
}

JsonTestClass c = new JsonTestClass();
c.Name = "test";
c.Test = c;
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject
               (c, new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });
```

We will get an exception:

> Self referencing loop detected for property 'test' with type 'Program+JsonTestClass'. Path ''.

But if we do it like this there is no error:

```
JsonTestClass c = new JsonTestClass();
c.Name = "test";
c.Test = new JsonTestClass();

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject
       (c, new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });
```

Comment: Alright, so this is by design then. Good enough for me.